# Rotating MapView in iOS6 on User Gesture

Tags: ios, ipad, mapkit

It seems you cannot rotate the map view using user's two finger gesture anymore. It has been a while since I did any iOS development but pre-ios6 it was automatically enabled.

Is this the case or is it me being ridiculous? It seems to me that its a very basic requirement for developers to be able to allow their users to rotate the map.

Any links to documentation that specifically says we can't rotate or some clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it was possible before iOS 6? I don't even think the Maps app in iOS 5 was able to do it.

Comment: you could make an overlayView over your mapView that handles a two finger gesture that does the exact same thing as that you want? Why not go for that solution?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus It just doesn't seem very efficient and elegant especially if it is built in.

Comment: @Scott I'm sure you could. Whether it was iOS5 or not I can't remember. I did quite a bit of work on the maps and can remember being able to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Try UIRotationGestureRecognizer to rotate map.Following code will help you.

```
   UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rgrr = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateMap:)];
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:rgrr];//mapView -->your mapview
rgrr.delegate = self;
```

////////

```
- (void) rotateMap:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
gestureRecognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(gestureRecognizer.view.transform, gestureRecognizer.rotation);
gestureRecognizer.rotation = 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If it comes to it and I have to implement something like this I will mark it as the answer

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet. Just waiting to see if its possible to do another way.